# Is it possible to get maven-jaxb-schemagen-plugin working with Java 7?

Tags: java, jaxb, java-7, schemagen

When I try to use `maven-jaxb-schemagen-plugin` with java 7

```
<groupId>com.sun.tools.jxc.maven2</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-jaxb-schemagen-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.2</version>
```

I get an error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.sun.tools.jxc.maven2:maven-jaxb-schemagen-plugin:1.2:generate (default) on project TopologyProvisionerDom: Execution default of goal com.sun.tools.jxc.maven2:maven-jaxb-schemagen-plugin:1.2:generate failed: A required class was missing while executing com.sun.tools.jxc.maven2:maven-jaxb-schemagen-plugin:1.2:generate: com/sun/mirror/apt/AnnotationProcessorFactory
```

It seems like the `AnnotationProcessorFactory` is being removed/deprecated in Java 7? Is it possible to get jaxb schemagen to work using this plugin? Is there an alternative approach to get schema generation from the JAXB source code when using JDK 7?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried using the [`org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/schemagen-mojo.html) instead?

Comment: So this plugin seems to work. One downside is that it doesn't seem possible to name the output schema files using this plugin, so I had to resort to using the maven-antrun-plugin to rename the schema file. Also I get a warning "warning: The apt tool and its associated API are planned to be removed in the next major JDK release." - hopefully this mess will get sorted out before java 8

Comment: You can provide the output schema files using <transformSchemas> and <transformSchema>

Answer (score 7):

This is how it works (add this profile to your `pom.xml`):

```
<profile>
    <id>jdk7-fix</id>
    <activation>
        <file><exists>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</exists></file>
    </activation>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.sun.tools.jxc.maven2</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jaxb-schemagen-plugin</artifactId>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
                            <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
                            <version>1.7</version>
                            <scope>system</scope>
                            <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</profile>
```

Comment: this look like a workaround for me, do you have a description for your solution ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure anyone is listening to this thread anymore but, what the hey...

I used the `transformSchemas` option e.g.

```xml
<transformSchemas>
    <transformSchema>
        <uri>YOUR NS IN YOUR GENERATED SCHEMA FILE</uri>
        <toFile>DESIRED NAME OF YOUR XSD FILE</toFile>
    </transformSchema>
</transformSchemas>
```

cheers

-m.